# animate on change of padding JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So i try to change my navbar, make it smaller when you scroll down, works perfectly, then I want it to get bigger when you scroll back-up, doesn't do a thing? I looked into the source step by step and my statements are good nothing wrong with that, anybody any idea?

```
 $(window).scroll(navbarSmaller);

function navbarSmaller() {
var docTop = $(window).scrollTop();

if(docTop > 20) {
    $("#navbar ul").animate({ 
        'padding' : 10
      }, "fast");
} else if(docTop <= 20) { 
    $("#navbar ul").animate({ 
        'padding' : 20
      }, "fast");
}
```

}

Comment: When you scroll all the way to the top and log `docTop`, what do you get?

Comment: `docTop is 0` sometimes something happens but most of the time not, now I see that after a while of waiting at the top, the navbar changes.

Comment: Should work https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/96Lpefys/1/

Comment: Try also https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/kgqfdnq4/14/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with adding a variable. I don't know if it's the right way but now it works very smooth.

```
var navbar = 1;
function navbarSmaller() {
var docTop = $(window).scrollTop();

if((docTop > 150) && (navbar === 1)) {
    $("#navbar ul").animate({ 
        'padding' : 10
      }, "fast");
      navbar = 0
} else if((docTop <= 150) && (navbar === 0)) { 
    $("#navbar ul").animate({ 
        'padding' : 20
      }, "fast");
      navbar = 1;
}
}
```

for people who wanted this.